# Debugging hanging app on OSX

Tags: macos, debugging, unity-game-engine, xcode-instruments

This question involves Unity3d, but it's not specifically about it.

I'm building a Unity project for OSX; as a result, I get complete .app that I can run — without xcode project in between, as on iOS. Everything goes OK, but my app hangs up from time to time, forcing me to kill it.

What OS X tools can I use to help with debugging such a situation? May be there's something in xcode instruments that can help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll want to get the crashlogs, which will give you the callstack, and therefore the location in the code of the crash.

Here's some info on how to find the crash logs:

http://serato.com/scratchlive/support/6600/how-to-get-a-crash-log-in-mac-osx

And here's some info about what to do with them once you have them:

[How to symbolicate Mac OSX crash reports issued by Apple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842147/how-to-symbolicate-mac-osx-crash-reports-issued-by-apple)

Comment: But there's no crash logs, because app just hangs, not crashes.

Comment: "What OS X tools can I use to help with debugging such a crash?" So if there's no crash, then you're talking about just using the debugger and breakpoints to see where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, I should've form the question better. But I don't build from an IDE, so I don't have any debugger at hand!